# Method: signupUrls.create cannot be create

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, android-management-api

```
After successful signin and gapiloaded 
below the error i get    
    
   code
        : 
        403
        message
        : 
        "Caller is not authorized to manage project."
        status
        : 
        "PERMISSION_DENIED"


<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for androidmanagement.signupUrls.create
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.androidmanagement.signupUrls.create({
      "callbackUrl": "xxxxx",
      "projectId": "xxxxxxx"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.

Comment: Are you trying to use the sign-in library for authorization?  [Separated Authentication and Authorization Moments](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview#separated_authentication_and_authorization_moments)

Comment: yes but could not able to solve

Comment: if you read the link i sent you thats because your using the wrong library. you should be using the authorization library not the signin library.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/signupUrls/create?apix=true from this i had got code

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that sample is up to date with the new library yet.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occurs if your project ID (ID of the Google Cloud Platform project which will own the enterprise) does not match to the account signed-in or vice versa. Another possibility is that the Android Management API may not have been enabled on the Google Cloud Platform project you are using.

Please double check your [Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) project ID to ensure your authentication account is included and the proper APIs are enabled..

> **Note:** The older Google Sign-In platform library: `apis.google.com/js/platform.js`, and [Google APIs client library for Javascript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client): `gapi.client` are no longer supported for user authentication and authorization. They have been replaced by a single new Google Identity Services Javascript: `account.google.com/gsi/client`.

If you are building a server-based solution, you can create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account) so you don’t need to authorize the access every time.